# How to set up Google Tag Manager in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-tag-manager

I'm currently looking into setting up Google Tag Manager in iOS Swift. The Google developer docs currently don't have anything on Swift, only on Objective-C. Does anyone have any experience with setting up GTM in Swift?

The current iOS docs can be found here: 
https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v3/

Thanks a lot to anyone who can point me in the right direction!

Comment: FWIW, the ios doc are outdated and the screenshots actually point to a prior version of GTM. Additionally, the code example in ObjC uses a deprecated call to load the container.

Answer (score 0):

first off I might be a bit too late in helping you here, secondly: I just started implementing this for my app today, and since I write it in `Swift`, I obviously have the same issue as you. However, I managed to install the SDK now and I can access the TAGManager and the code to open the container.

I installed the SDK using CocoaPods, so unless you also do that I can't really help you with adding the SDK to your project. I would really recommend using CocoaPods though. But since the SDK is written i `ObjC` you need to bridge the `header files` in order to use it in `swift`.

Here is the CocoaPod for Google Tag Manager: https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleTagManager

And here is the link I used to get the `header files` to bridge:http://thiagoborg.es/blog/2014/10/29/manage-objective-c-dependencies-with-cocoapods-on-swift-project/

In the link you provided I'm currently at Getting Started - 3. Opening a Container. Unfortunately I can't get it to open, it stated that it can't find my binary.

Hope this helps somewhat, though :)!

Answer (score 0):

Anyone coming across this may have been frustrated by the rogue tutorials floating around for version 3 of Google Tag Manager. Your Bridging header will not compile !

What you want is the version 5 of Tag Manager

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5/#fire-tags

Answer (score 0):

The current version of GTM for Swift is 7.x.x which relies on FirebaseCore  10.x.x and GoogleAnalytics 3.x.

To setup GTM 7.x.x:

1. Create a folder `container` on the same directory as `*.xcodeproj`, `*.xcworkspace`.
2. Add the folder to the Xcode project. Make sure to select `Create folder references` and select `Target Membership` as the project's primary target.

[image]

3. Copy the `GTM-xxx.json` in to the folder. DO NOT rename the `GTM-xxx.json`.
4. Build and run, the console should output `GoogleTagManager info: Loading container: GTM-xxx`.